# Derivative of the error w.r.t parameters

Tags: neural-networks, derivative

let's assume my function is as simple as

$y = xW + b$

We define an error function as $E = {\frac{(t - y)}{2}}^2$

I wonder if you can help me to write the derivative of the error w.r.t parameters (W and b) and how I can represent the model as a computational graph, and illustrate how automatic differentiation works.

Comment: With respect to which parameters do you want to differentiate? And what variables are vectors? Please use $\LaTeX$ to typeset mathematics, and not code brackets.

Comment: Hint: You need the power rule of derivatives and the chain rule of derivatives.

Comment: @AdrianKeister updated as requested :-) by parameters I mean w and b

Answer (score 0):

You first need to plug in the equation for $y$ into the error equation like:

\begin{equation}
E = \frac{1}{2}[t - (xW + b)]^2
\end{equation}

then get the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial E}{\partial b}$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the derivatives w.r.t. matrices and vectors can be quite tricky. However, they can typically be broken down to scalar equations as follows:

$$y = b + \sum_j x_j w_j$$

In order to get the gradient w.r.t. the vector $W$, you just need to compute the gradient w.r.t. every entry $w_j$. The result will again be a vector.

Apart from that, you will need the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) as indicated by other comments and answers